# Set a dedicated 'emacs' key in Linux like OSX

Tags: linux, xorg

I use emacs quite a lot, and on Mac OSX, most of the Control-keybindings from emacs are available in nearly all applications (e.g. Control-A goes to the beginning of the line) whilst the more common CUA keybindings are under the command key (e.g. Command-S saves a file)

How can I set this up on X11 so that one of Control and Super handles emacs keybindings and the other one is for CUA keybindings? I see that there is an emacs gtk key theme, but it uses control and overwrites/disables the CUA keybindings.